# What's a good environment in which I can provide word definitions in the body of a text?

Tags: formatting

I'm writing a dissertation and want to define some key terms. Now, I do this just with itemize and use the indented little bullet point. It looks ok, but I guess one of the advantages of LaTeX is that I can dream bigger and find more aesthetic options.

However, when I google "word definition environment in LaTeX" I get exclusively hits for maths-related topics. Do any of you have a good suggestion for an environment in which I can define a term in such a way that it is offset from the surrounding text?

Here's what I do now:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \begin{document}

 Many terms are important, including surprising ones. In this treatise, we use the word \textit{potato}, like so:

\begin{itemize}
\item Potato. Species of ghost native to Mexico.
\end{itemize}

Therefore, we propose that potatoes be dug up and reburied in accordance with proper rites.
 \end{document}
```

But I'd prefer to have something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

Many terms are important, including surprising ones. In this treatise, we use the word \textit{potato}, like so:


Potato. Species of ghost native to Mexico.
% Where the above is nicely indented, offset from the rest of the paragraph, so readers can easily find it.

Therefore, we propose that potatoes be dug up and reburied in accordance with proper rites.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This question is too broad and is soliciting primarily opinion-based answers. Please make this decision yourself and then rephrase your question.

Comment: I don't even know what options there may be though.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Do your research and find something you like, and then ask about that specific thing.

Comment: But I can't find anything, that's basically what I'm asking.

Comment: If you show with a MWE what you have now it is much easier to see what you are asking for. Then, complemented with a good description of how you want it to look you can expect some answers. At least to me it is not clear what you are looking for as the question is stated now.

Comment: You need a bit of markup, so use something like the following `\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\indent--~#1\par\vspace{\baselineskip}}`  and in you document use `\keyword{Potato. Species of ghost native to Mexico.}`. The definition needs to be refined, importat is that you use a special command.

Comment: why not `\begin{description}\item[Potato:] Species of ghost native to Mexico.\end{description}`? Anyway, for "nice formating", you need to give `latex` clues about what is the word you define, what is its definition, and how you want to render the word and the definition. I.e. you will need some syntax (through macros), and - in the preamble - some layout definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...is nicely indented, offset from the rest of the paragraph, so readers can easily find it.

[`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s list formatting capability for a `description` environment does this, in my opinion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{worddefs}{description}{1}
\setlist[worddefs]{font=\sffamily\bfseries, labelindent=\parindent, leftmargin=6em, style=sameline}

\begin{document}

Many terms are important, including surprising ones. In this treatise, we use the word \textit{potato}, like so:

\begin{worddefs}
  \item[Potato.] Species of ghost native to Mexico.

  \item[Potato.] Species of ghost native to Mexico. Species of ghost native to Mexico.
    Species of ghost native to Mexico. Species of ghost native to Mexico.

  \item[Potatomato.] Species of ghost native to Mexico.
\end{worddefs}

Therefore, we propose that potatoes be dug up and reburied in accordance with proper rites.

\end{document}
```